# how to make file redirect to to page after success process

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I am working with **php 7.2** and **laravel 5.5**

this my **blade.php** that the issue in there

```html
    @extends(MyHelper::siteTheme('billing_waiting'))

@section('contentBlock')

    <h3>
        {{trans('site.blockchain.send')}} <span style="color:red">{{ $form_data['amount']}} </span>BTC <br>
        {{trans('site.blockchain.to')}} <span style="color:red">{{ $form_data['sendto']}} </span>
    </h3>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h2>{{trans('site.blockchain.scan')}}</h2>
    {!!  $form_data['code']  !!}
    <br>
    <br>
    <h3 style="color: red;">** {{trans('site.blockchain.confirmations')}}</h3>

@endsection
```

and this is my call back file

```
if ($order->btc_amo==$value_in_btc && $secret=="ABIR" && $confirmations >= 1){

                $savedata['confirmation'] = $trx_hash;
                $savedata['gateway_response'] = json_encode($request->all());
                $savedata['status'] = 'paid';}
```

now i want to make the **blade.php** return to specific page when callback return success 
means when

> ($order->btc_amo==$value_in_btc && $secret=="ABIR" && $confirmations >= 1)
>   return to success page

thanks in advance

EDIT:

i want the blade file refresh and go to specific page when the payment goes successful from the callback file

this my full callback file

```html
$track = $request->input('invoice_id');
            $secret = $request->input('secret');
            $value = $request->input('value');
            $confirmations = $request->input('confirmations');
            $value_in_btc = $value / 100000000;
            $trx_hash = $request->input('transaction_hash');

            $order = Transaction::where('hash',$track)->first();

            if($order->status == 0){
                
                if ($order->btc_amo==$value_in_btc && $secret=="ABIR" && $confirmations >= 1){
                    $savedata['confirmation'] = $trx_hash;
                    $savedata['gateway_response'] = json_encode($request->all());
                    $savedata['status'] = 'paid';

                    //Update product sales
                    $this->salesupdate($order->product_id);
                    //Save order
                    $this->neworder($order->user_id,$order->product_id,$order->price,$order->hash,$order->id);
                    //Save user transaction
                    $this->newusertransaction($order->user_id,$order->price);
                    //Credit seller
                    $this->creditseller($order->product_id);
                    // add balance to user
                    $this->addbalancetouser($order->user_id,$order->price);
                    //Update order
                    $order->update($savedata);

                    
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you please more detail about this. What you wants to do exactly?

Comment: i want when payment goes successfully the blade file return to specific page

Comment: ok you can't redirect to blade file. You need to create a route and against this route you need to creat a function and load blade template  and redirect to link like this
return redirect('your_route');

Comment: Are you making the request (to your callback) through ajax, by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

your question is bit unclear. you can use `redirect('url')` to rediect to another page and you can use `with()` if you need to send some data. so just at the end of the callback you do this,

`return redirect('your-page-url')`

you can find more info in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/redirects)

hope this helps!

Comment: this will not work in the blade file i want to make redirect when the process goes successful from the call back file

Comment: then you need to use java script ans ajax to make your request and redirect

Answer (score 0):

Return

```
redirect("route of url")
```

to direct that specific url when successful

Comment: this will not work in the blade file i want to make redirect when the process goes successful